# Constraints in constrOptim.nl in r

Tags: r, optimization, nan

I am using R package `costrOptim.nl`.

I need to minimize a function with the following constraints:

`Alpha < sqrt(2*omega) and omega > 0`

In my code expressed as:

```
theta[3] < sqrt(2*theta[1]) and theta[1] > 0
```

I write these conditions as:

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zj1b1.png)

But when I call `optimizer` and run it.

I'm getting the following problem:

```
1: In sqrt(2 * theta[1]) : NaNs produced
```

Why? Did I set the proper conditions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Can you please modify your code so it's clear what exactly is being executed?

Comment: of course. i have a very long code. thank you for the suggestion

Comment: Thanks, that's better, but I suggest including some more work, such a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1) where we can run your code an get the same error message you're getting on your machine.  Your first two lines of code still look like pseudo-code.  (If not --that's your problem  --R uses the `&` for the `and` operator).

Answer (score 0):

```
This is my whole code. 

data <- read.delim(file = file, header = FALSE)
ind <- seq(from = 1, to = NROW(data), by = 1)
data <- data.frame(ind = ind, Ret = data$V1, Ret2 = data$V1^2)

colnames(data)[1] <- "Ind"
colnames(data)[2] <- "Ret"
colnames(data)[3] <- "Ret2"
T <- length(data$Ret)

m <- arima(x = data$Ret2, order = c(3,0,0), include.mean = TRUE, method = c("ML"))

b_not <- m$coef

omega <- 0.1
alpha <- 0.005
beta <-  0.9

theta <- c(omega,beta,alpha) # "some" value of theta

s0 <- theta[1]/(1-theta[2])


theta[3] < sqrt(2*theta[1]) # check whether the Feller condition is verified 

N <- 30000 
reps <- 1
rho <- -0.8
n <- 100

heston.II <- function(theta){
set.seed(5)
u <- rnorm(n = N*reps,mean = 0, sd = 1)
u1 <- rnorm(n = N*reps,mean = 0, sd = 1)
u2 <- rho*u + sqrt((1-rho^2))*u1

sigma <- matrix(0, nrow = N*reps, ncol = 1)
ret.int <- matrix(0, nrow = N*reps, ncol = 1)
sigma[1,1] <- s0

for (i in 2:(N*reps)) {
sigma[i,1] <- theta[1] + theta[2]*sigma[i-1,1] + theta[3]*sqrt(sigma[i-1,1])*u1[i]
 # if(sigma[i,1] < 0.00000001){ sigma[i,1] =  s0}
}

for (i in 1:(N*reps)) {
ret.int[i,1] <- sqrt(sigma[i,1])*u2[i]
}


ret <- matrix(0, nrow = N*reps/n, ncol = 1)
ret[1,1] <- sum(ret.int[1:n],1)

for (i in 2:((N*reps)/n)) {
ret[i,] <- sum(ret.int[(n*i):(n*(i+1))])
ret[((N*reps)/n),] <- sum(ret.int[(n*(i-1)):(n*i)])
}

ret2 <- ret^2 

model <- arima(x = ret2, order = c(3,0,0), include.mean = TRUE)

beta_hat <- model$coef
m1 <- beta_hat[1] - b_not[1]
m2 <- beta_hat[2] - b_not[2]
m3 <- beta_hat[3] - b_not[3]
m4 <- beta_hat[4] - b_not[4]

D <- cbind(m1,m2,m3,m4)

DD <- (D)%*%t(D)/1000
DD <- as.numeric(DD)
return(DD)

}

heston.sim <- heston.II(theta)

hin <- function(theta){
h <- rep(NA, 2)
h[1] <- theta[1] 
h[2] <- sqrt(2*theta[1]) - theta[3]
return(h)
}

hin(theta = theta)

.opt <- constrOptim.nl(par = theta, fn = heston.II, hin = hin)
.opt
```

Comment: Two things: (a) move this code from an 'answer' to the 'question' (you can edit questions and (b) this example is probably  more complicated than you need to demonstrate the problem you're facing.  Read and follow the advice of [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example?rq=1).